# Horizontal align inside dd

Tags: css

```css
    div {
        display:inline-block;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    dl {
        width :100%;
        overflow :hidden;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding :0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    dl dt {
        float :left;
        width :200px;
        margin :0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding: 0px 0px 1em 0px;
    }
    dl dd {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding: 0px 0px 1em 0px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <dl>
      <dt>Some title</dt>
        <dd>
          <input />
          <br />
          <input/>
          <br />
          <textarea></textarea>
          <br />
          <input />
          <br />
          <input />
          <br />
        <dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Hello,

I have the above code.

The result is different in all the browsers than the result in this snippet:

In real life. the 1st input in dd is aligned on the same line with the dt, to the right.

The second input is aligned under the 1st one. but starting the 3rd input, all the inputs in the dd fall under the dt to the left.

I can't manage to align all the text and input in dd at the same level, without falling to the left under dt at the 3rd row.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks, Alex

Comment: You are not supposed to use this for forms.

Comment: I've removed the *dd* tag as it doesn't refer to the HTML element *dd*.

Comment: I found the solution, second answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160934/how-to-float-left-with-dd-and-dt
http://jsfiddle.net/fWeec/